# Is That A True Markup situation?

Tags: html

i add the "canvas" markup tags to that collection of images

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="97%">
    <tr>
        <canvas>
      <td width="3%">
      <img border="0" src="style/2day/images/hed_01.jpg" width="64" height="133"></td>
      <td width="94%" align="center" background="style/2day/images/hed_04.jpg">
      <img border="0" src="style/2day/images/hed_02.jpg" width="594" height="133" align="center"></td>
      <td width="3%">
      <img border="0" src="style/2day/images/hed_05.jpg" width="61" height="133"></td>
        </canvas>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Is That true???

Answer (score 3):

Those `<canvas>` tags are completely out of place; this doesn't look like an occasion where you would use canvas. In any case, if you open a tag in the `tr` row context you will have to close it before opening the `td` cell context.

Comment: but why i must close `tr` tag before `td` tag

Answer (score 2):

http://validator.w3.org/check says this about your fragment:

> Validation Output: 7 Errors
>
> Line 1, Column 118: Attribute bordercolor not allowed on element table at this point.
>   `…pacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="97%">`
>
> Line 1, Column 118: The border attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>   `…pacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="97%">`
>
> Line 1, Column 118: The cellpadding attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>   `…pacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="97%">`
>
> Line 1, Column 118: The cellspacing attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>   `…pacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="97%">`
>
> Line 1, Column 118: The width attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>   `…pacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="97%">`
>
> Line 3, Column 16: Start tag canvas seen in table.
>    `<canvas>`
>
> Line 3, Column 16: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
>    `<canvas>`

That last line means the parser got totally lost. So your html is definitely not fine and chances are that browsers will not display as expected.